# How do I keep Robot test suites DRY?

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework

I'm halfway through a set of automated tests using the Robot Framework, and am starting to notice a lot of repetition. At the moment, my tests are organized by the page being tested (i.e. homepage, login page).

The uncertainty I'm feeling is that some tests are word-for-word repeated in two different test suites, with only the setup differing; but on the other hand, with the refactoring I've done, it feels like the keywords themselves are the test cases. I just want to know if there's a more standard practice way of doing this.

I've listed a trivial example below:

common.robot

```
...
*** Keywords ***
User logs in
   # login logic here
...
```

home_page.robot

```
...
*** Test Cases ***
Verify user login
   User logs in
...
```

other_page.robot

```
...
*** Test Cases ***
Verify user login
   User logs in
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to share test keywords, you can do that on many levels.

1. So you could define a resource.txt file and put all your common keywords in there and then call them for different tests.
2. You can have a single parent test where you are simply reusing keywords with the differing parameters.
3. You could also feed the parameters through a list and call the same keyword in a For loop.

That being said, regarding your bigger concern of how to organize the structure of your test suite, that is a much-discussed topic and no single answer would suffice. You could look at the Pekka's writings on this topic [(Link)](http://eliga.fi/writings.html).
Test-framework-design is an 'art-form' similar to code design.

Comment: Ahh, could you elaborate on point 2? How would test files call that parent test?

Comment: Sure. So the best way to accomplish this is as follows. First, generalize your keywords as much as you can. So in your example, you would also pass the page link as part of your keyword. Second, keep your keywords in a common file/place so that they are accessible by your parent test. Finally, construct your test using the 'meta' keyword keywords in the built-in library in robotframework such as 'Run keyword if', 'Run keyword and return status', run keyword and ignore error' etc.

Comment: Ok, got a little lost on the third step. I would put a "User logs in" test case in the parent file; and then I can call the test from another file using Run Keyword? Can a test case be called like a keyword?

Comment: Robot framework is very flexible and so there are a couple of ways to go here as well. You could convert your test cases to keywords and that would enable the structure that I mentioned. That would be my preferred way. OR if you must preserve the structure of your test cases, then you could go a different route altogether and define an argument file for running your tests. More on that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16322798/is-there-a-way-to-get-robot-framework-to-run-test-suites-in-a-certain-order).

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I have options to explore...too many options.