# How can I run my files under a pycharm file in order?

Tags: pycharm, robotframework

I have a file and below that file my files are sorted alphabetically. When I run this file, pycharm runs the following files mixed. I want these files to run in alphabetical order. How will I do this?

Comment: Why PyCharm? I think you need to run them in Python, so just do a script in python which sort files and it execute them (sorted). You can do this in PyCharm. And you can set a run target in PyCharm to run such program. But PyCharm is an IDE (so to write programs), it should not be the standard way to execute programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add prefixes like 01 and 02 into file and directory names. Such prefixes are not included in the generated test suite name if they are separated from the base name of the suite with two underscores:

```
01__my_suite.robot -> My Suite
02__another_suite.robot -> Another Suite
```

Check Robot Framework's documentation for this here:
[Robot Framework execution order](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#execution-order)

Also this post might be useful:
[how to run test suites in a certain order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16322798/is-there-a-way-to-get-robot-framework-to-run-test-suites-in-a-certain-order)